# Coloring tables

Tags: color, list-manipulation, visualization, display

Is it possible to apply a color function to table cells based on the magnitude of their content? For instance, in the table

```
TableForm@Table[10^(x + y), {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}]
```

I would like the cell background color to change from blue for small numbers in the top left to red for large numbers in the bottom right. (Other than the background, the cell content should remain unaffected.) Is this possible?

Comment: Do you need to display the numbers too?  If not, `ArrayPlot` has a `ColorFunction` option.

Comment: @Alan Yes, the numbers too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
table = Table[10^(x + y), {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}];

(* You have to manually set the second argument according to the content of the table. *)
rescale = Rescale[Log[10, #], {0, 8}] &;

color = Blend[{Red, Blue}, rescale[#]] &;

TableForm@Map[
  Style[#, color[#]] &,
  table,
  {2}
  ]
```

[image: table1]

Edit 1: I have just realized, that you asked for coloring the background of cells. Just a small change in code is needed.

```
TableForm@Map[
  Item[#,
    Background -> Directive[Opacity[0.7], color[#]]
    ] &,
  table,
  {2}
  ]
```

[image: table2]

Edit 2: Extension to incorporate wish from OP comment.

```
table = Table[{x, y, 10^(x + y)}, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}];

TableForm@Map[
  Item[#,
    Background -> Directive[Opacity[0.7], color[#[[3]]]]
    ] &,
  table,
  {2}
  ]
```

[image: table3]

Comment: @Two more questions: 1. What if the table is `Table[{x,y,10^(x + y)}, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}]`? 2. How can I reduce the opacity of the cell background?

Comment: Nice. One last thing: Is there a way to make this work with `TableForm`, as used in the OP?